# IF user Enters 5 character or more , Then the search bar should display the Full location address using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a scenario like, IF user Enters 5 character or more , Then the search bar should display the Full location... As Of Now it is working when I clicked on the Button , But I need to get the full address into the search bar when I enter 5 characters without clicking on the button.......
For example :  If I type Dallas in the search bar , then it should show like this :  "Dallas, Texas, United States" without clicking on the button......
Please can Anyone help me in this, Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import * as getallcoordiantes from '../../src/Redux/googlemaps/bigbasket.actions';

const GetGeoCoordinates = () => {

    const [storeDetails, setstoreDetails] = useState({
        name: ""
    });
    const [validCityName, setvalidCityName] = useState(false)
    const [refObj, setrefObj] = useState({
        geo: {
          lat: 32.776272,
          long: -96.796856,
        },
        name: "Dallas",
        palce: "US",
      });
    const [warning, setwarning] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const storeInfo = useSelector((state) => state.fetchAllData.storeInfo);

    useEffect(() =>{
        if(storeInfo?.features){
            //console.log(storeInfo?.features[0]?.place_name)
            //setstoreDetails({ name: storeInfo?.features[0]?.place_name });
            const coordinates = storeInfo?.features[0]
            ? storeInfo?.features[0].center
            : [];
            // console.log(coordinates);
            //console.log(storeInfo?.features[0]?.text);
            if(coordinates[0] === refObj.geo.long && coordinates[1] === refObj.geo.lat){
                if (refObj.name !== storeInfo?.features[0]?.text) {
                  setwarning("Entered City Name is Invalid");
                } else {
                  setstoreDetails({ name: storeInfo?.features[0]?.place_name });
                  setwarning("");
                }
              } else {
                setwarning("Please Enter a Valid City");
              }
             }        
    },[storeInfo])
    
    const hanldeChange = (e) => {
        let newStoreDetails = { ...storeDetails };
        newStoreDetails[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        // console.log(newStoreDetails);
        setstoreDetails(newStoreDetails)
    }

    const getStoreDetails = () => {
        if(storeDetails.name.length <=4){
            setvalidCityName(true)
        }else{
            setvalidCityName(false);
            dispatch(getallcoordiantes.fetchcoordinates(storeDetails.name));
        }
    }


  return (
    <div>
    <h2>Search For Store</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={storeDetails.name} onChange={(e) => { hanldeChange(e) }} />
        <button onClick={getStoreDetails} type="button">Get Location</button>
    </form>
    {validCityName &&  <p>Type Minimum 5 Characters</p>}
    <p>{warning}</p>
</div>
  )
}

export default GetGeoCoordinates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add 1 `useEffect` hook which will watch for changes of `storeDetails?.name` and will execute your `getStoreDetails` function, the one that is attached as button click handler, on any change of `name` entered.

```
const getStoreDetails = () => {
  if (storeDetails.name.length <= 4) {
    setvalidCityName(true);
  } else {
    setvalidCityName(false);
    dispatch(getallcoordiantes.fetchcoordinates(storeDetails.name));
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  getStoreDetails();
}, [storeDetails?.name]);
```

Comment: Its Working fine, but I am getting a warning message like  "Please Enter a Valid City" although the entered  city name is correct .... That error msg  should come when there is no match for the city.. Can you please look into this and let me know what to change?

Comment: @sundeep it comes down here from your states. Like `storeInfo`, and `getallcoordiantes` and im not seeing them. Based on your question i was sure everything else just works. without a reproducable example i will not be able to help. And i guess that will be another question in terms of StackOverflow

Comment: Ok I have made that into another Question, Can you please look into this and give me the solution
link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519930/error-message-should-show-only-when-the-city-name-doesnt-match-using-reactjs

Comment: @sundeep I would like to but sorry, I have no clue about how redux works and how your state is managed there, but maybe someone will be able to help. Also, probably you should include the details about  `getallcoordiantes.fetchcoordinates` in your created question, append the code of this method to the question you created.